# Получить порт из ByteBuffer

Tags: java, kotlin, port

У меня есть перехваченный пакет в виде ByteBuffer, как из него нужно достать порт в java/kotlin?

Comment: ByteBuffer это данные, переданные по сети. Вы ожидаете видеть порт в переданных данных?

Comment: Вы должны знать, где в этом пакете расположен порт, обычный порт занимает 2 байта, т.e. по сути имеет тип short, зная смещение, по которому расположен порт, можете достать его оттуда методами класса `ByteBuffer`, например `getShort`